# Data Source Name Not Found And No Default Driver Specified

Tags: java, odbc

I am trying to connect to MS Access database from my Java application. This is my code:

```
try {
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
// set this to a MS Access DB you have on your machine
String filename = "UserInformation.accdb";
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
database+= filename.trim() + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true}"; // add on to the end
// now we can get the connection from the DriverManager
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","");
Statement st= con.createStatement();
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into Users(User_Name,User_Password)             values('"+username+"','"+password+"')");
System.out.println("Row is added");
}catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

I get this exception: Data Source Name Not Found And No Default Driver Specified (ODBC)?

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you have to specify the **full** path to the database file, e.g: `jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=c:\my\database\UserInformation.accdb;DriverID=22;READONLY=true`

Comment: I already tried it. Also I put my database in my project folder too.

Comment: Now I get no suitable driver found exception

Comment: I hope MS Access driver is installed on your system.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It can be several things. I encountered this problem in hacking a database from a 32-bit machine on my 64-bit desktop.

If you google issues using odbc with 32 vs 64 bit in Java you will see a good amount of material. What ultimately worked for me was switching from Java 5 to 6 and making sure my Eclipse runtime configurations were not setting an incompatible bit-mode.

Sorry for being a bit vague, but after spending a few hours trying to figure out I believe it can be very situational dependent.